# Two separate generic types have the same erasure?

Tags: java, generics

I stumbled upon an interesting error that I've never seen before, and can't explain why

Consider the following class

```
public class Sandbox<A,B> {
 public void put(B b) {
 }
 public void put(A a) {
 }
}
```

Looks okay to my eyes. So I compile it and then get this

```
name clash: put(B) and put(A) have the same erasure
```

Huh? How do two different generic types have the same signature? There completely separate!

I'm probably missing something completly basic, but I've just not run into this issue before. I've band-aid fixed the problem by calling the methods `putA` and `putB`, but I'm really curious to why this error happened in the first place.

Would someone mind explaining?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Logically, consider the following code:

```
SandBox<String, String> sandBox = new SandBox<String, String>();
sandBox.put("foo"); // which put is invoked?
```

(Although I should admit that it's possible to produce perfectly valid code that produces similar situations - and then a method is chosen at "random".)

Formally, I think [this section of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#38649) is relevant. Both versions of put have the same argument types - if I read that section correctly.

Comment: I like this counter example very much -- makes it a lot clearer than the other answers that go into detail about generics being implemented via erasure.  However, it doesn't explain why the similar declaration of the class 'SandBox<A extends Number,B extends CharSequence>' leads to the same compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

Generics in Java are only available at code level and not at runtime.

So when the compiler translates your sourcecode, the types you specified for A and B are "erased". This means both types are set to `java.lang.Object`.

So you end up with two identical method signatures.

Comment: Not relevant in this case. It doesn't make sense even if you could overload on non-erased types. And being able to overload with matching erased types could be done without reification.

Answer (score 1):

> How do two different generic types
>   have the same signature? There
>   completely separate!

Java generics are based on [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). That means your code basically compiles to this:

```
public class Sandbox{
 public void put(Object b) {
 }
 public void put(Object a) {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Huh? How do two different generic types have the same signature? There completely separate!

The root of your problem appears to be that you do not have a good grasp of Java terminology.

The compiler is **not** telling you that two generic types have the same signature:

- Types (generic or otherwise) don't have signatures in the formal sense.  Methods have signatures.
- `A` and `B` are not generic types.  They are type parameters.
- The things that the compiler tells you have the same signature are `put(A)` and `put(B)`.  These are methods, not types.

**EDIT**

OK ... so you *do* understand the terminology.

If you use technical terminology incorrectly, don't be surprised if:

- some people misinterpret your questions (and answers),
- some people call you out for using terminology incorrectly, and
- some people discount what you ask / say as being uninformed.

But the case I'm worried most about (*and the real reason I took the time to answer your question!!*) is when some poor confused Java newbie does a Google search, finds your SO question full of sloppy terminology, and gets *even more confused*.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking clearly at the time. By signatures I meant method signatures. Eg `public void stuff()`. And I randomly picked generic types since it sounded correct. As you can see, I'm not the person that quotes terms from the JLS